# Plug in assemblies for Windows Service

Tags: c#, plugins, windows-services

I am looking at designing a Windows Service that can act in a way that can run "modules" or plug-in assemblies.

The Service will be written in C# and .NET 7 or 8.  The entire solution should connect to databases, get information, and send to a web API.

My thinking for modules is centered around having to support different database technologies (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres etc.) that need  to be connected to.  The Service ideally has no knowledge of each database technology, it should deal with the web API for messaging.  So the plug in modules/assemblies interact with databases, and the service interacts between modules and web API.

Modules will provide a multi-threaded approach for interacting with many database instances - doing work and returning results (messages) when done to the service.

Ideally, the existence of an assembly (let's say SQLServer.dll for example) means the Service picks this up and uses it to talk to SQL Server databases (based on provided configuration).  If the assembly does not exist or is not configured to be used, it is ignored.

I have looked at this project and it looks promising https://github.com/natemcmaster/DotNetCorePlugins

Are there other alternatives?   In experimenting with dynamically loading assemblies using reflection I have found one limitation to be I can't seem to pass / return complex objects because of namespace clashes.  So I don't even think just putting all the database responsibility into its own project and namespace will work.

It looks like the above approach solves this.  I've also read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support

So to summarise my question(s):

Is this a good idea?
Are there any pitfalls with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

The DotNetCorePlugins solution sounds like the best approach and to be fair is similar to how I've designed a Windows Service framework with a plug-in design for the specific implementation detail.

The key thing here is to ensure you design a set of contracts by way of Interface declarations that any plug-in no matter what the purpose so long as the intention is the same, such that whatever concrete implementation is drawn in for use at runtime (via Assembly Load techniques etc.), the shape of that implementation regarding the methods to invoke etc., are all predetermined through the Interface declarations.

Things may get a little complicated based on your exact circumstances if you want for example to load multiple database provider assemblies (e.g., to handle interactions with SQL, Oracle etc.,) in the same Windows Service instance, but essentially it's all about being able to load a *specific assembly* at runtime, or *specific assemblies* if required, then being able to dispatch requests into them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks - good reminder too about interfaces!